# I want to remove Print Invoices from mass action select menu available on order view page in admin order panel

Tags: magento2

I want to remove Print Invoices from mass action select menu available on order view page in admin order panel.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Override `../vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Remove below code from it:

```
<action name="pdfinvoices_order">
    <settings>
        <url path="sales/order/pdfinvoices"/>
        <type>pdfinvoices_order</type>
        <label translate="true">Print Invoices</label>
    </settings>
</action>
```

You can place xml file in your custom module of in app/design theme with same path to override.

Comment: I tried to override in theme but it dosen't work app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Magento_Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Comment: Place it in your custom module that will work fine! app/code/<vendor name>/ <module name>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Comment: I already tried in custom module also but dosen't worked :(